# Trying to Mock a DataService Publisher in Combine Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, combine

When I use a publisher that actually makes an api call everything works fine.  However, if I try to Mock it I get a crash that says EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16b827ed0).

Here is the viewModel:

`

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var dataString: String = ""
    
    let dataService: DataServiceProtocol
    
    init(dataService: DataServiceProtocol) {
        
        self.dataService = dataService
        self.nasaPublisher
            .assign(to: &$dataString). // The app crashes here when i use the mock data service
    }
    
    private lazy var nasaPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = {
        $dataString
            .flatMap { [unowned self] string in
                
                self.dataService.getNasaData()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }()
}
```

`

And here is the data service:

`

```
enum Endpoint: String {
    case search = "/search"
}

protocol DataServiceProtocol {
    func getNasaData() -> AnyPublisher<String, Never>
}

class DataService: DataServiceProtocol {
    
    let host = "https://images-api.nasa.gov"
    
    func getNasaData() -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {

        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = "https"
        components.host = "images-api.nasa.gov"
        components.path = "/search"
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: "apollo")
        ]
        
        guard let url = components.url else {
            return Just("false").eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
          .map { data, response in
            do {
              let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                
                print(data.prettyPrintedJSONString)
              return str
            }
//            catch {
//              return "false"
//            }
          }
          .replaceError(with: "false")
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    }
}

class MockDataService: DataServiceProtocol {
    
    let mock = Just("Test string")
        .setFailureType(to: Never.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    
    func getNasaData() -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        
        return mock
    }
    
}
```

`

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

I've ran and tested the code with a real api call and it works fine but crashes if I use the mock api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `init` you have:

```
        self.nasaPublisher
            .assign(to: &$dataString)
```

So this is a publisher that assigns its output to the published variable `dataString`

Then `nasaPublisher` is defined as:

```
    private lazy var nasaPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = {
        $dataString
            .flatMap { [unowned self] string in
                
                self.dataService.getNasaData()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }()
```

This is a publisher that reacts whenever the value in `dataString`  changes.

When `dataString` changes it causes `nasaPublisher` to emit a value.  That value is assigned to `dataString` which causes `nasaPublisher` to emit a value. That value is assigned to `dataString` which causes `nasaPublisher` to emit a value. That value is assigned to `dataString` ...

It's an infinite loop.

When you're using your real data service, it creates a unique publisher each time the loop calls `getNasaData`.

When using your mock service, however it creates one publisher and `getNasaData` returns the same one every time.

That one publisher is going to execute once then release any assets it has.  I suspect the second time through the infinite loop one of those assets has been released, causing a crash.